# Does a public webserver need to accept incoming from more than port 80?

Tags: iis-7, windows-firewall

Probably in than email is outgoing means servers have to reply but beyond that, what's the bare minimum portlist that a public-facing webserver (iis7 with same-box sql) have to admit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using defaults -

80 is HTTP

443 is HTTPS

Just 80 if you don't use HTTPS

And then any ports you need open for remote access if you need it.

Answer (score 5):

Just 80 is all you need for public web service.
Add 443 if you have SSL in the mix.